# How plot Pie_chart in python while having 3 columns of data

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, pie-chart

| Charging | Number | Share |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0-20%. | 9. | 15.50% |
| 21-40%. | 18. | 31%. |
| 41-60%. | 4. | 6.90% |
| 61-80%. | 9. | 15.50% |
| 81-100% | 8. | 13.80% |
| >100% | 10. | 17.30% |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pie()` function from `pyplot` to draw pie charts in python. First you need to install `matplotlib`:

```
pip install matplotlib
```

Then you can create pie charts by providing the sizes and labels:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = 'Charging', 'Number', 'Share'
sizes = [20, 9, 15.5]

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, labels=labels, startangle=90)
ax1.axis('equal')

plt.show()
```

Pie chart documentation: [pyplot-pie](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html)

Comment: Yes you are right, but i am looking for pie_chart with % sign and also the value for " Charging " is from 0-20%, So i am facing how to mention "-" whereas python takes it as minus, but in my data is from 0 to 20%. Can you please guide.

Comment: Hi Hanan. You need additional logic to represent percentage ranges. You can find an example with percentages here: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_and_donut_labels.html